# how to add 2 java projects to the same bit bucket repository

Tags: java, git, bitbucket, bitbucket-cloud

I created a new bit bucket Repo,and a new Java project and I linked them,now I can commit and push and do all those operations.
Now I created a  second hello world Java project and when I try to push to the same bit bucket Repo,I get "push rejected".
Can one bit bucket Repo hold one Java project?Or how is it?Sorry I am a beginner to git and BitBucket,any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about bit bucket but the general practice is one repository holds one project. With that in mind, you need a different repository for each project, two in your case.

See this doc for Git: https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line